# How to make only listview scroll not without changing state of bottomsheet

Tags: android

I am using bottom sheet to show an image. there is a button in bottom sheet , when it is pressed the image is replaced by list view . But when i scroll the list it drags the bottom sheet. Is there any way i can scroll list without changing state of bottom sheet.

Comment: Please add some code what you have tried

Comment: its obvious that on scrolling the list from bottom to top it drags the bottomsheet to change its state from expanded to collapse. nothing i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

dont write your whole code in `ScrollView` , whatever you write in it is scrollable..... if you just want your `listView`to be scrollable then don't use `ScrollView` anywhere because `listView` is already scrollable by default``

Answer (score 0):

```
final BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                        }
                    });
```

this code did it if anyone else want.Thanks to them who tried to help me